# Programmatically access all videos on wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am currently developing an video backup/upload app which requires me to programmatically access all videos on wp8; irrespective of whether they are on phone or sd card.

Is there any way by which we can programmatically access all videos in wp8 ?

Well I do know that there is a way to integrate the app with the [video hub](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769558%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). I also know that it is possible to save files using the app specific [Isolated Storage](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-Jump-Start/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-Jump-Start-04-Files-and-Storage-on-Windows-Phone-8).

But my boss requires that..

```
 1) Videos list should be displayed in the app itself without integrating with the video hub.
 2) App should not use only the videos from the Isolated Storage because that will greatly restrict the apps functionality.
```

I mean can I get the same list of videos as is shown the inbuilt video hub? If there are no managed options then can it be done using native code ?

Answer (score 3):

Sadly there is no API in Windows Phone 8 for accessing videos just like you can do it with photos.
The all you can do right now is vote for this API to be added in future version of Windows Phone [**here**](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/1897833-video-chooser-task) or [**here**](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/3153734-access-video-music-library) on WPdev UserVoice page.

But there might be an option to access stored videos using the File type associations:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Well I understand that the medialibrary could be used to access pictures & music; and that it does not allow managed code to access video files in any way. But as a last option are the any ways to do this natively using c++ ; I mean write something from scratch. Would it be too difficult or as good as impossible ?

Comment: As I said, there is no API for gathering the list of videos, but there might be an option how to get access to videos, using the File type associations: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987(v=vs.105).aspx